# How can i used the andriod studio in AWS remote server

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio

I wanted to use the android studio in the AWS remote server with ec2 instance then what type of processor should I use .

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Android Studio [system requirements](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), look at the different types of [EC2 instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), and pick one that is sufficient.